Update R packages with PAK after new release
I often resort to
update.packages(checkBuilt=T, ask=F) 

After a new R release. However, I normally use the excellent pak package for installing R packages. Does anyone know how to update all the packages built with a previous R version using pak?
Thanks!
I googled and read the pak documentation.

Generally old school, but <- installed.packages(), then, taking note of unique(all_pkgs[, 2]) # LibPath, I have 571 installed from CRAN, 171 from github, so two different setdiff to compare for packages after upgrade to R-4.4.0. I was hoping you'd go first...but, I've been thinking about it. After save(.

Did you ever try this?

honestly not. as much as I like pak and other tools, this is way too complicated with respect to the base R approach.

I found this works well on Windows 11
pak::pkg_install( unname( old.packages()[ , "Package"] ) )


Which OS are you on as it helps future readers assess.

This is applicable to R on linux. List all packages installed prior to upgade to new R version
all_my_pkgs <- installed.packages()
save(all_my_pkgs, 'Rpackages')

Upgrade R painlessly @pedro-rafael
install.packages("ropenblas")
    ropenblas::rcompiler(x='4.4.0')

Close terminal session, start new session in magically upgraded R-4.4.0 and load('Rpackages') returns all_my_pkgs, and R440_pkgs <- installed.packages() to compare and build names vector of packages we want pak::pak to install. Which I forgot to install. Install pak.
my_pak_dreams <- setdiff(as.vector(unname(all_my_pkgs), mode = 'character'), as.vector(unname(R440_pkgs2[,1]), mode = 'character'))

pak::pak(c(my_pak_dreams))

have a go
error in pak subprocess
Caused by error: 
! Could not solve package dependencies:
* brainconn: Can't find package called brainconn.
* luna: Can't find package called luna.
* tabulizer: Can't find package called tabulizer.
* tabulizerjars: Can't find package called tabulizerjars.
* vscDebugger: Can't find package called vscDebugger.


oops. Take those out i.e. dreams2 <- setdiff(all_my_pkgs and c('brainconn', & etc.
Missing 8 system packages. You'll probably need to install them manually:
+ libfftw3-dev     - fftw, OpenImageR         
+ libgdal-dev      - sf, terra, vapour        
+ libgeos-dev      - sf, terra, lwgeom        
+ libnetcdf-dev    - ncdf4                    
+ libnode-dev      - V8                       
+ libpq-dev        - RPostgres                
+ libproj-dev      - sf, terra, vapour, lwgeom
+ libsndfile1-dev  - seewave                  
? Do you want to continue (Y/n)

Open another terminal and install what you need. I build spatial from source so won't install libgdal-dev, libgeos-dev or libproj-dev, but yes to the others. (And libnode errored so wasn't clear that others were picked up...)
Start installing 591 packages 11:18. 376/591 12:11.
 590 pkgs + 1 dep: kept 14, upd 2, added 575, dld 544 (471.15 MB) [1h 25m 22.9s]

12:40. Done. If you're on Windows/Mac, your approach to install new version of R will be different, but the pak::pak stuff... Painless.
